# Get data from Database using Controller xamarin Forms (MVC)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need a help..
I need to get data from database using Controller.. But nothing happens when I do it.
My api is php codeigniter and i'm using X-API-Key.. I want to use It in MVC structure, because I need my view be navigable.

**HttpClient**

```
public class HttpClient
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> _headers;
        private HttpClient restClient;

        public HttpClient(Dictionary<string, string> headers)
        {
            if (headers != null) _headers = headers;
            else _headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        public string this[string Key]
        {
            get
            {
                return _headers[Key];
            }
            set
            {
                _headers[Key] = value;
            }
        }

        ///<Summary>
        /// HTTP GET REQUEST
        ///</Summary>

        public async Task<HttpResponse<T>> ExcecuteAsync<T>(Method method, string baseUrl, Dictionary<string, object> formdata = null)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest(method);

            foreach(var header in _headers)
            {
                request.AddHeader(header.Key, header.Value);
            }

            if(formdata != null)
            {
                foreach(var item in formdata)
                {
                    request.AddParameter(item.Key, item.Value);
                }
            }

            IRestResponse response = null;
            Exception ex = null;
            try
            {
                response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
            }
            catch(Exception _ex)
            {
                ex = _ex;
            }
            var httpresponse = new HttpResponse<T>
            {
                Response = response
            };

            if (response == null)
            {
                httpresponse.Status = new StatusResponse
                {
                    code = -1,
                    message = $"Nao se pode obter resposta do servidor, stacktrace:{ex.StackTrace}"
                };
                return httpresponse;
            }
            var jsonresult = response.Content;
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

                var telement = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonresult);
                httpresponse.Result = telement;
            }else if(response.StatusCode == 0)
            {
                httpresponse.Status = new StatusResponse
                {
                    code = 0,
                    message = $"Nao se pode obter resposta do servidor"
                };
            }
            else
            {
                var telement = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StatusResponse>(jsonresult);
                httpresponse.Status = telement;
            }
            return httpresponse; //null


        }
```

**This is my App.xaml - where i have my x-api-key**

```
    App.RestClient = new HttpClient(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"X-API-Key", "926ff4c0-d86e-421f-9192-82ac52650f5c" }
                });

                App.BaseUrl = "http://10.156.96.80/apiuthomi";

protected override async void OnStart()
        {

            var ListasHospitais = await new HospitalService(App.RestClient).all();
            MainPage = new ListHospital(ListasHospitais);
        }
```

**This is ListHospital.xaml**

```
<StackLayout>
                <ListView
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                      x:Name="ListasHospitais"
                      IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                      Margin="10">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10" BackgroundColor="White"  Margin="0 , 0 , 0, 10">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                       VerticalOptions="End"
                                       Text="{Binding Nome}"
                                       MaxLines="1"
                                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"

                                      />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                       Text="{Binding Detalhes}"
                                       VerticalOptions="Start"
                                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                       MaxLines="2"
                                       />
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
```

**This is my ListHospital.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class ListHospital : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Cliente> _clientes;
        public ListHospital(List<Cliente>clientes)
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            _clientes = new ObservableCollection<Cliente>();
            ListasHospitais.ItemsSource = _clientes;

            foreach(var cliente in clientes)
            {
                _clientes.Add(cliente);
            }
        }
        public void voltar_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PopAsync();
        }

    }
```

**HospitalService = where i will write all methods**

```
public class HospitalService
    {
        private HttpClient _restclient;

        public HospitalService(HttpClient restclient)
        {
            if (restclient != null) _restclient = restclient;
            else throw new NullReferenceException("http nao pode ser nulo");
        }

        public async Task<List<Cliente>>all()
        {
            var response = await _restclient.GetAsync<List<Cliente>>("http://10.156.96.80/apiuthomi/cliente/all");
            if (response.Result != null) return response.Result;
            return new List<Cliente>();

        }

    }
```

**until here everything is going well and it's working**.. but the problem is that my view listHospital os no longer clickable.. like I want tho make this page be navigable...

this  `public ListHospital(List<Cliente>clientes)`does not allow the clicked method to be valid in my view

Comment: there is no useful information here we could use to help you.  Where is the relevant code?  What **specifically** do you need help with?  Getting data from the database in your API method?  Or calling your API from Xamarin?  Or something else?  Please read [ask] for guidance on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I'm sorry for not making it clear before

Comment: "the problem is that my view listHospital os no longer clickable" - then this has nothing to do with your database or your API or your http client.  You just need to add an ItemTapped or ItemSelected handler to your ListView

Comment: The problem is not that @Jason.. I have a login view, after I login I have a grid of views, so this ListHospital is one of them and I'm testing it using it, but because of this line **public ListHospital(List<Cliente>clientes)** I can't do **await Navigation.PushAsync(new ListHospital())** , It give me an error, so I want other way to do this or get data. this is my problem.

Comment: 1. The ListHospital  is a ContentPage not a View. 2. Where do you want to call  `await Navigation.PushAsync(new ListHospital())`? In the constructor of ListHospital(I don't think it is a right way)?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT - No I call it in other view, not in this ListHospital.. I have a view named PlacesListView, where I have 4 Views. so I call this `await Navigation.PushAsync(new ListHospital())` in PlacesListView to push ListHospital.. the error `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'clientes' of 'ListHospital.ListHospital(List<Cliente>)'`

Comment: I think Jason's answer is right to your question and you can mark it which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Thanks guys it's working!

Answer (score 0):

> I can't do `await Navigation.PushAsync(new ListHospital())` , It give
>   me an error

this is because your `ListHosptial` page does not have a default (empty) constructor and you are not passing the required data.  You can fix this by adding an default constructor

```
public ListHospital()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

    ...
}
```

if you do this then `ListHospital` needs to load it's own data.  The easiest way to do this is probably to add a call to your services in the `OnAppearing` method

```
public override async void OnAppearing()
{
  // call services to load data and assign ItemsSource
  var data = await new HospitalService(App.RestClient).all();
  ListasHospitais.ItemsSource = data;
}
```

Comment: you do it the exact same way you do it in your other page.  See my edit